# C# Linq to XML query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

```
<World>
  <Animals>
    <Tab>
      <Dogs id ="1">
        <Dog1></Dog1>
        <Dog2></Dog2>
        <Dog3></Dog3>
      </Dogs>
      <Dogs id ="2"></Dogs>
      <Dogs id ="3"></Dogs>
    </Tab>
  </Animals>
</World>
```

How do I get all elements under  tag where id == 1?

My Linq query. (doesn't work) why?

```
XDocument xml= XDocument.Load(xml.xml);
var elements = from e in xml.Descendants("Animals").Descendants("Tab").Elements("Dogs")
where e.Attribute("id").toString().Equals("1")
select c;
```

Could you check it please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = xdoc.Descendants("World")
                 .Descendants("Animals")
                 .Descendants("Tab")
                 .Elements("Dogs")
                 .Where(n => n.Attribute("id").Value == "1");
```

Output:

```xml
<Dogs id="1">
  <Dog1></Dog1>
  <Dog2></Dog2>
  <Dog3></Dog3>
</Dogs>
```

Comment: Thank you!! Problem was in n.Attiribute("id").VALUE. ( I forgot add .value)

Answer (score 1):

From your sample data I think you want

```
//from e in xml.Descendants("Animals").Descendants("Tab").Elements("Dogs")
from e in xml.Descendants("Animals").Elements("Tab").Descendants("Dogs")
```

And in the same line, `Descendants("Animals")` could be `Elements("Animals")` if you want to enforce the structure.

For the rest your query looks OK.

Answer (score 1):

Or use XPath:

```
xml.XPathSelectElements("/World/Animals/Tab/Dogs[@id=1]")
```

or

`xml.XPathSelectElements("//Dogs[@id=1]")`

which would find all Dogs wherever they occurred.

Comment: Only if you want Dogs outside of "Animals" too.