# How to Read xml data when i pass specific id?

Tags: c#, xml

i have requirement that  i have to read xml data for specific id. for example  i want to
  retrieve all district names in   id:21. can any one please help me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Rnames>
<org id="19">
<District name="District 19A1"/>
<District name="District 19A2"/>
<District name="District 19A3"/>
<District name="District 19A4"/>
</org>
<org id="20">
<District name="District 20A1"/>
<District name="District 20A2"/>
</org>
<org id="21">
<District name="District 21A1"/>
<District name="District 21A2"/>
<District name="District 21A3"/>
<District name="District 21A4"/>
</org>
<org id="22">
<District name="District 22A1"/>
<District name="District 22A2"/>
</org>
<org id="23">
<District name="District 23A1"/>
<District name="District 23A2"/>
</org>
</Rnames>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to read XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Linq to XML query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363361/c-sharp-linq-to-xml-query)